# NameError: name 'average' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning

**How to filter the data from the dataframe using avg for replacing null values**

When running this snippet of code:

```
df.select(colname).agg(avg(colname))
```

I receive this exception:

```
name error: avg not defined
```

*what other command can I use?*

Answer (score 3):

got it..

have use..

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

Answer (score 3):

it would be cleaner a solution like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(colname).agg(F.avg(colname))
```